# PostgreSQL Order by not working, it doesn’t returns values according to the order

Tags: postgresql, count, group-by, sql-order-by

I have two tables players and scores. 
On the player table I have two fields, name and id (PK)
On the scores I have several fields [id_score(PK),winner and looser are foreign key to the id of the player]
id tournament and id match.

```
Players
 id_players |   name    
------------+-----------
         41 | Antonia
         42 | Roberto
         43 | Luis
         44 | Pedro
         45 | Fernando
         46 | Alejandra
         47 | Rene
         48 | Julieta

Scores
id_score | id_matches | winner | looser | id_tournament | round 
----------+------------+--------+--------+---------------+-------
       19 |         22 |     41 |     42 |            21 |     1
       20 |         23 |     43 |     44 |            21 |     1
       21 |         24 |     45 |     46 |            21 |     1
       22 |         25 |     47 |     48 |            21 |     1
       23 |         26 |     43 |     41 |            21 |     2
       24 |         27 |     45 |     47 |            21 |     2
       25 |         28 |     42 |     44 |            21 |     2
       26 |         29 |     48 |     46 |            21 |     2
       27 |         30 |     43 |     45 |            21 |     3
       28 |         31 |     42 |     48 |            21 |     3
       29 |         32 |     41 |     47 |            21 |     3
       30 |         33 |     46 |     44 |            21 |     3
```

I'm trying to get a query that contains the following: 
id of the player
name of the player
number of wins
total games

Currently I have these query. It kind of works. When I do the order by, it's not returning items on the correct orders

```
select p.id_players,p.name,count (s.winner) as wins, max(s.round)
from players p 
left join scores s on s.winner = p.id_players 
group by id_players, s.winner
order by s.winner desc;

 id_players |   name    | wins | max 
------------+-----------+------+-----
         41 | Antonia   |    2 |   3
         42 | Roberto   |    2 |   3
         43 | Luis      |    3 |   3
         45 | Fernando  |    2 |   2
         46 | Alejandra |    1 |   3
         47 | Rene      |    1 |   1
         48 | Julieta   |    1 |   2
         44 | Pedro     |    0 |
```

Comment: When you say it is not returning the "correct" order, what order is it that you wanted to see? The column you have selected to order by is a numeric ID, so the results are sorted in numeric order. Maybe you meant to do `order by p.name`?

Comment: Perhaps you just want `order by wins desc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, it is easier to use subqueries:

```
select p.*,
       (select count(*)
        from scores s
        where p.id_players in (s.winner, s.loser)
       ) as GamesPlayed,
       (select count(*)
        from scores s
        where p.id_players in (s.winner)
       ) as GamesWon
from players p
order by GamesWon desc;
```

If the maximum of the round is the number of games played, then similar logic will get that.

Comment: Although the question isn't entirely clear, I'm not sure this answers it. The question is about the `order by`, but you seem to have instead come up with an alternative method of grouping.

Answer (score 6):

The ordering works as it should. The problem is you are asking it to order by `s.winner` which refers to the ID of the winning player. If you want to order them based on most wins, you need to use `ORDER BY wins DESC`, maybe with a secondary order clause for ties. Then the rows would start with the player with maximum number of wins.

A bit more logical query would be

```
SELECT s.winner, p.name, count(s.winner) as wins, max(s.round)
  FROM players p
    LEFT JOIN scores s ON s.winner = p.id_players 
  GROUP BY s.winner
  ORDER BY wins DESC;
```

This way you don't need two `GROUP BY`s since `s.winner` is the same as `p.id_players` anyway.

Comment: My use case was different but the point you made about accidentally sorting by an id helped me find my bug. Thanks for the extra detail!